# grammaticality of the question "is it idiomatic what"

Tags: grammaticality

When I formulate questions to post on this site, I often want to write something like

> Is it idiomatic what I have written above?

After giving some examples at the top of my question, I want to ask whether what I wrote above is correct. But I have doubts about the grammaticality of this construct.

Do you think this construct is acceptable in English speech?

Comment: *Is it idiomatic when I say ....*  or  *Is what I have written idiomatic?*

Comment: It's a bit strange that your sentence is about "what I have written above" but you're asking if it is "acceptable in English *speech*". I think in real life, people sometimes say something similar: *Is it idiomatic, what I just said?* or *Is it idiomatic? I mean, what I just said.* It's because it's spontaneous. If we have a little time to think about what we're going to say, then it's more likely that it'll come out as *Is what I've just said idiomatic?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it would sound slightly more idiomatic (heh) to say:

> Is what I have written above idiomatic?

or even, simply, if you're writing this immediately after the thing you're asking about:

> Is this idiomatic?

However, that's not to say that your phrasing is *wrong*, per se (though I'd recommend using a comma - see examples below). You might hear, for example:

- Is he generous, then, your brother-in-law?
- Is it well paid, your new job?
- Is it far, your house, from the station?

These, though, are more common in spoken English (or written forms that more closely correspond to spoken English, like text messaging or instant messenger). For written questions on StackExchange, it sounds a bit better to use one of the two I have at the top.

Comment: Useful to know. Thanks. So I can use it in spoken English.

Answer (score 2):

One standard way of asking a question is 'Is (something) (adjective)?', for example 'Is it correct/standard/idiomatic/acceptable?'. You can also specify what 'it' is: 'Is (what I have written above) idiomatic?'. You really don't need to write 'it' and 'what I have written above' in the same sentence, because they refer to the same thing.